# Optional to hide CupertinoTabBar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm not actually sure whether this is a flutter issue or a usage issue. Either way, I want to hide the CupertinoTabBar in some specific screens.
Imagine my app widget tree is:

`MaterialApp
 - Login => To log in and navigate to Dashboard
 - Dashboard (is CupertinoTabScaffold with parallel bottom navigation bar by CupertinoTabBar)
  - A (a tab) => CameraPage => Submit Form (also have the bottom navigator bar)
  - B (a tab) => Foo
  - C (a tab) => Baa`

Everything is work perfectly, exclude the Camera page always have the bottom navigation bar. I tried using the `Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)` and the navigator bar is been hide, but when I press a button to navigate to Submit Form, this page will be lost the navigator too.
I want the CupertinoTabBar to have a property (let say `isShow`) and when `isShow` is false, the navigator will be moved out of the screen by the transform, etc.

Comment: ,, Were you able to find a solution to your issue?

Comment: @user2570135 I must custom the CupertinoTabBar. I add a Transform widget and a flag to hide the bar by moving the bar to outside the screen.
Not the best practise, but that's all thing I can do

Comment: `Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)` did the trick for me but only my main view uses a bottom navigation bar.

Comment: @BasicCoder amazing!! worked like a charm!! hahah